# C# Webbrowser Control weBrowser.Navigate fails on long URL

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, hresult

For some reason when I try to perform a navigate to a long URL:

```
webBrowser.Navigate(Url, "_self", null, "Referer: " + Referer);
```

I get the following error:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> The ErrorCode -2147467259

Is there a URL length that I don't know about?

Could there be an issue with my version of IE or .NET?

Comment: The Web Browser control is basically a hook to whatever version of IE is installed on that system. What's the URL in question? Does it work in IE?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, IE versions prior to 9 have a known URL limitation of 2083 bytes. It appears to have been increased in 9, but have not found a definitive resource yet.

There does not appear to be any change in IE9 (since MS didn't trumpet it as an amazing breakthrough), so unless something definitive turns up, it has to be assumed that IE9 has the same limitation.

See [this MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427) for details.